# Getting Name,Phone Number and Email Address From Phone Contacts

Tags: android, email, button, contacts, android-contacts

I needed to Create a project that getting the `Name,Phone Number and Email Address` from a selected contact from the Phones Default contact list.
 Steps:
   When I clicked a button in my application it will open or go to the default phone contact. After that I select a phone contact it will comes back to my application and there is 3 text View to place the Name,Email and phone number. How can i Achieve this?
 Thanx in advance

Comment: Try something and show your code. Don't expect others just to do your job for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it this way for `Android 2.2 Froyo` release: basically use `eclipse` to create a `class` like: `public class SomePickContactName extends Activity`

then insert this code. Remember to add the private class variables and CONSTANTS referenced in my version of the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
  Intent intentContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI); 
  startActivityForResult(intentContact, PICK_CONTACT);
}//onCreate

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) 
{

  if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT)
  {         
    getContactInfo(intent);         
    // Your class variables now have the data, so do something with it. 
  }
}//onActivityResult

protected void getContactInfo(Intent intent)
{

   Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(intent.getData(), null, null, null, null);      
   while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
   {           
       String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
       name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)); 

       String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

       if ( hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
           hasPhone = "true";
       else
           hasPhone = "false" ;

       if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) 
       {
        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext()) 
        {
          phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        }
        phones.close();
       }

       // Find Email Addresses
       Cursor emails = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId,null, null);
       while (emails.moveToNext()) 
       {
        emailAddress = emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
       }
       emails.close();

    Cursor address = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId,
                null, null);
    while (address.moveToNext()) 
    { 
      // These are all private class variables, don't forget to create them.
      poBox      = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POBOX));
      street     = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET));
      city       = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY));
      state      = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION));
      postalCode = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE));
      country    = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY));
      type       = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE));
    }  //address.moveToNext()   
  }  //while (cursor.moveToNext())        
   cursor.close();
}//getContactInfo
```